# How to prevent python playwright timing out when taking many screenshots

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, chromium, playwright-python

I am trying to take multiple screenshots of a reddit thread using playwright. It works by starting at the first xpath of the first element of the thread and then increments that xpath till it reaches a non-existent xpath. It works for the first 27 screenshots but after that it times out.

```py
import pickle
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright,Page
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context =browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    context.add_cookies(cookies)
    #this is the link it goes to to begin taking screnshots
    page.goto('https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/11iwm33/who_is_a_bad_guy_in_history_who_actually_wasnt_a/')
    #reloads just to make sure there are no popups
    i=2
    page.reload()
    page.set_viewport_size({"width": 640, "height": 480})
    page.reload()
    page.reload()
    #this loop keeps going till a invalid xpath is found and screenshots it.
    while True:
        try:
            page.locator("xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[%s]"%i).screenshot(path='screenshots/'+(str(i)+'.png'))
            i+=1
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

I havent tried much because there seems to be little answers that fix the problem all though I believe that the reason why this occurs is that the javascript on the page is being executed so much it causes a timeout.
Also as the screenshots get made they get slower and slower towards the exception that breaks the screenshot loop. I also tried writing the exact same program with Selenium and got the same results and I figured by changing librarys I may be able to get different results but I actually go the exact same error I was trying to run from.

This is the error

```
Timeout 29656ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
taking element screenshot
  waiting for element to be visible and stable
    element is not visible - waiting...
============================================================
```

Edit the issue may have been this because its trying to take a huge screenshot
[image]

Comment: The error is clear: locators wait for their specified element to appear and time out when it doesn't appear. How would you screenshot something that doesn't exist? Maybe you want to screenshot the whole page in the `except` block?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would screenshot the entire page if that is what is needed but I just want the reddit comment boxes. I think its a javascript based issue because the screenshots become progressively slower.

Comment: I'd worry about correctness first, then performance next. You can screenshot whatever you want, but you can't screenshot that doesn't exist. That'll timeout. Once you fix that by screenshotting something that exists, then work on improving efficiency.

Comment: Im sorry for not writing my question clear enough, It takes 27 screenshots in the exact manner it is supposed too but on the 27th it stops working, freezes dead in it tracks and then time outs.

Comment: No problem. The question is clear, I think. I think there's a misunderstanding where you expect it not to time out, but that's what locators always do when the element they're looking for never exists, so this is the expected behavior for this code.

Comment: Okay Im seeing the issue thanks. I understand what you mean know because there are divs without content that trip it up, thanks alot.

Comment: The locator should still find those regardless of its content, but glad you worked it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A blank div caused this error to occur